Is there a format for scholarly writing that allows you to cite "where did I find this citation?"
I know in many fields such as journalism there is usually a notion of "primary, secondary, tertiary sources" in that you can directly cite someone at an event, or cite a citation of them etc...
I wanted to develop a similar idea in mathematics.
Sometimes when reading a paper you are not only interested in the results and what sources are cited while developing the results but rather the meta-question of "what sources did this person use to find their sources in the first place?"
Perhaps an aggregator like Wikipedia but more obscure would be useful for readers to know about and there's not usually any way to directly mention such things in citations for mathematics.
On a more humane level hypothetically if Bob at Room 204 in the department happens to be able to point lots of people to useful literature then you would want to have a ton of meta-citations for "Bob" so they can be appropriately rewarded by society. Currently they do this work and receive no benefit to their H-index. (Maybe at most some Thank You's in the acknowledgement sections of large papers).
Does there exist some (possibly not well known) scientific citation format that allows you to include these kinds of meta-citations?
If I had to invent such a format I might do it the following way:

Use Endnotes to directly cite sources for mathematical results
At the back where the Endnotes are cited, include additional Endnotes so I can cite "where/how was this endnote even found in the first place".
Recursively (repeat (2)) onto itself, until all credit has been duly given to any sources and individuals that helped me find the current useful set of sources.


In science, "Bob" is a bibliography. For every scientific field and for many subfields, there is a scholarly bibliography that lists publications in that field. Today those bibliographies are usually databased. Part of the education of every scientist is to get to know the bibliographic databases in their field. Besides that, professionals in a field attempt to read or at least skim all the publications in their field. The effect is that they know the field and its publications. Thus, every scholar knows the usual steps another scholar has probably undertaken to find the sources they have used in their papers (using their memory, browsing the publications they have read, and using one or more bibliographic databases).
I don't see why this information needs to be repeated in every publication, since it is well-known.
The purpose of citations in scientific writing is to substantiate established facts (as they have been published in peer-reviewed publications), not to illustrate the process of how the author came by these facts, as that is irrelevant to the scientific argument.

If you are interested in the structure of cross-references, there are cross-disciplinary citation indexes like Google Scholar, Crossref, CiteSeer, Science Citation Index (part of Web of Science), and Scopus as well as a large number of citation indexes for specific scholarly fields such as PubMed or Astrophysics Data System that list (some) of the (known) publications that cite a specific work. I don't think any of these services make all of their data publicly available, but you can certainly enquire with them or try and extract the information that you are interested in, either manually or using a custom built scraping tool that compiles the information you seek into whatever form you envision.

Please comment if I misunderstood your question.
